# spreadsheet get filter and create filter in one assignment

Tags: google-apps-script, filter, spreadsheet

the code work if the .getFilter() put infront and .createFilter() put at back, this always works in sheet no matter i manually put filter (DATA->CREATE A FILTER) or i manually remove the filter.

But if i put the .createFilter() || .getFilter() , the code won't work if there is already existing filter in the sheet.

The logical OR is read from left to right , if the 1st criteria don't meet will jump to 2nd criteria. But why if there is a filter in sheet (.createFilter() will be false), it should jump to 2nd criterial (.getFilter()), but it shows errors.

THE CODE:

```
var myRange = mysheet.getRange(1,1,mysheet.getLastRow(),3);
  var myFilter=myRange.getFilter() || myRange.createFilter();
```

explain on why getfilter() must put infront.

Comment: Can you provide the error message of `but it shows errors.`?

Comment: This error when you already had a filter in the sheet when u use below code
=> var myFilter=myRange.createFilter()||myRange.getFilter() ;

Exception: You can't create a filter in a sheet that already has a filter.
myFilterTest @ Code.gs:10

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `This error when you already had a filter in the sheet when u use below code => var myFilter=myRange.createFilter()||myRange.getFilter() ; Exception: You can't create a filter in a sheet that already has a filter. myFilterTest @ Code.gs:10`, in this case, when `myRange.createFilter()` is false, `myRange.getFilter()` is used.

Comment: By this, when the basic filter has already been set, such an error occurs. I think that this is the reason for your current issue. In this case, I would like to recommend using `var myFilter=myRange.getFilter() || myRange.createFilter();` in your showing script.

Answer (score 0):

> But why if there is a filter in sheet (.createFilter() will be false), it should jump to 2nd criterial (.getFilter()), but it shows errors.

This is because `createFilter()` doesn't return `false` as you expect. It throws a error, when there's already a filter. Returning from a function and throwing a error are two different processes.